# Как правильно вывести в listview данные из параметризованного списка list<>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Изучаю wpf, не могу вывести список в listview. Хочу использовать MVVM, Есть у меня Model, где готовятся данные, есть ViewModel, где я готовлю данные для View. Но в итоге они не показываются. Как вывести правильно?

`MainViewModel`:

```
class MainViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    ReadyData Rd = new ReadyData();

    public string FileName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FileNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FileNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FileNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FileName", typeof(string), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public Bitmap Iconka
    {
        get { return (Bitmap)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(Bitmap), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null
        ));

    public string Path1
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Path1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Path1Property, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Path1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Path1", typeof(string), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string ComandLine
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ComandLineProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ComandLineProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ComandLineProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ComandLine", typeof(string), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(""));


    public string Signature
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SignatureProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SignatureProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SignatureProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Signature", typeof(string), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string TrustSignature
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TrustSignatureProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TrustSignatureProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TrustSignatureProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TrustSignature", typeof(string), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string Zapusk
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ZapuskProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ZapuskProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ZapuskProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Zapusk", typeof(string), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string CompanyName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CompanyNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CompanyNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CompanyNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CompanyName", typeof(string), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public ICollectionView Items
    {
        get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Rd.Data());
    }

}
```

`ReadyData` - Model, где я подготавливаю данные:

```
public class ReadyData
{
    Controller c = new Controller();

    public List<info> Data()
    {
        string r1 = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
        string r2 = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";

        List<info> a = c.PrintKeys(r1);
        List<info> a1 = c.PrintKeys(r2);
        List<info> aSh = c.PrintTasks();
        List<info> a3 = c.Startfolder();

        // убираем одинаковые элементы
        List<info> result = a.Except(a1).ToList();
        var result1 = aSh.Union(a3);
        List<info> big = result.Union(result1).ToList();

        // убираю дубликаты записей
        var query = big.GroupBy(x => x.Namefile1).Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

        int b = query.Count();
        return query;
    }
}
```

Xaml разметка:

```
    <Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="276" ItemsSource="{Binding Items }" Margin="62,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="707">
            <ListView.View >
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Имя файла" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Иконка" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Iconka}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Путь" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path1}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Кпараметры командной строки" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ComandLine}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Цифровая подпись" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Signature}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Корректность цифровой подписи" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TrustSignature}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Тип запуска" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Zapusk}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Производитель" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CompanyName}"/>


</GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Ну и `MainWindow`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        //  DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не вижу где вы устанавливаете ItemsSource

Comment: @АндрейNOP а я не ставил его, не знаю где правильно его поставить

Comment: В разметке: `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вот так я прицепил.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Отображается только один столбец, который у называется Путь,а остальное пусто

Comment: Из всех свойств работает только Path1, остальные в ексепшенах пишут? что not found

Comment: Класс `info` покажите

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо  разобрался, проблема была в несоответствии имен в классе info, и имен в разметке, они должны быть одинаковые. И тогда всю коллекцию выводит. И чтобы вывести всю коллекцию нам нужно только лишь свойство ОДНО public ICollectionView Items, где  ICollectionView все и сделает, WPF это супер)